# How do you make clothes move along with model

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, cloth-simulation

how do you make clothes move along with your model? Do you rig the model first and then parent it to the body of the character then click cloth simulation? I am a little bit confused with the process. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If your character is rigged right, the above should work. You may need some cloth pinning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup some **pinned vertices** on your cloth mesh.

1. Create vertex group with pinned vertices:

[image]

2. Enable Pinned and use that vertex group:

[image]

3. Done. Now your pinned verts will follow the movement of cloth object. You can parent it to bone or some other object.

[image]